# removing element from mootools sortable

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools-sortable

I'm trying to remove an item from a mootools sortable list, then serialize and save the new list.

I'd like to use a little bit of eye-candy rather than a straight `destroy()` on the element. I've built a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kBAqJ/4/

Note the `order1` and `order2` vars. This holds the serialized element before and after removing the item. If you use the `destroy` method to get rid of the element after removing it from the sortable, you get the right value for `order2`, eg. 4.

If you use `nix(true)` instead of `destroy`, you get 5 as the value of `order1` and `order2`, even though the docs say that `nix(true)` calls `destroy` after `dissolve`.

Is this a bug in Mootools, or am I missing something? Is there a different way to add a `dissolve` effect while still using `destroy` that will get the right result?

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){

    var mySort = new Sortables('#example2 UL', {
        clone: true,
        revert: true,
        opacity: 0.7
    });

    console.log (mySort.elements.length);
    var order1 = mySort.serialize(0);
    console.dir(order1);

    mySort.removeItems($('item1')).destroy(); // this results in the correct value in the order2 var below
    //mySort.removeItems($('item1')).nix({duration: 1000}, true); // this results in the wrong value for order2

    console.log (mySort.elements.length);
    var order2 = mySort.serialize(0);
    console.dir(order2);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you'll find any effect or way which will destroy the element and still show it on the page ;) So it is not a moo tools bug

The serialize function is using the children of the list (ie. the `<li>` blocks) to make the array.

I would say the easiest way would be to get rid of their reference in the serialized array:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){

    var mySort = new Sortables('#example2 UL', {
        clone: true,
        revert: true,
        opacity: 0.7
    });

    console.log (mySort.elements.length);
    var order1 = mySort.serialize(0);
    console.dir(order1);

    //mySort.removeItems($('item1')).destroy(); // this results in the correct value in the order2 var below
    mySort.removeItems($('item1')).nix({duration: 1000}, true); // this results in the wrong value for order2

    console.log (mySort.elements.length);
    var order2 = mySort.serialize(0).erase("item1"); // we have to erase the item because he may still be in the list of children at this time…
    console.dir(order2);

});
```

Cheers

Comment: @romain-- thanks, but the issue is that `destroy` works as expected, while `nix` does not-- the mootools docs say that `nix` calls destroy AFTER it does the dissolve effect-- so one would expect that it would work the same as a straight `destroy` would, no?

Comment: @julio - the problem here is that you call serialize before the destroy occurs. the nix does the effect and then destroy. in your example the nix starts, takes 10000 ms to finish, the serialize occurs during this delay and then destroy is called… I don't see any mootools bug, it's the expected result for me…